# How to launch the Play framework console?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I downloaded and run Play 2.x and it starts the Activator webapp console. I'm interested in Play, not in Activator. How to launch the Play console? The installation only creates an 'activator' directory.

[This is what I'm looking for](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/PlayConsole#Launching-the-console)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`activator` is `play`. Look at the migration guide please: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration23

So you can use 'activator ui' command or 'activator', 'activator console' from the project directory.

> activator to run the console. See Using the Play console.